# TIC-TAC-TOE(Крестики-нолики)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class TicTacToeBoard:
    def __init__(self):
        self.clear_place = [['-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-']]
        self.p = self.clear_place
        self.end_info = 0
        self.list = ['X', '0']
        self.n = 1

    def new_game(self):
        self.clear_place = [['-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-']]
        self.p = self.clear_place
        self.end_info = 0
        self.list = ['X', '0']
        self.n = 1

    def get_field(self):
        return self.p

    def check_field(self):
        if (self.p[0][0] == 'X' and
            self.p[0][1] == 'X' and
            self.p[0][2] == 'X') or \
                (self.p[1][0] == 'X' and
                 self.p[1][1] == 'X' and
                 self.p[1][2] == 'X') or \
                (self.p[2][0] == 'X' and
                 self.p[2][1] == 'X' and
                 self.p[2][2] == 'X') or \
                (self.p[0][0] == 'X' and
                 self.p[1][1] == 'X' and
                 self.p[2][2] == 'X') or \
                (self.p[0][2] == 'X' and
                 self.p[1][1] == 'X' and
                 self.p[2][0] == 'X') or \
                (self.p[0][0] == 'X' and
                 self.p[1][0] == 'X' and
                 self.p[2][0] == 'X') or \
                (self.p[0][1] == 'X' and
                 self.p[1][1] == 'X' and
                 self.p[2][1] == 'X') or \
                (self.p[0][2] == 'X' and
                 self.p[1][2] == 'X' and
                 self.p[2][2] == 'X'):
            return 'X'
        elif (self.p[0][0] == '0' and
              self.p[0][1] == '0' and
              self.p[0][2] == '0') or \
                (self.p[1][0] == '0' and
                 self.p[1][1] == '0' and
                 self.p[1][2] == '0') or \
                (self.p[2][0] == '0' and
                 self.p[2][1] == '0' and
                 self.p[2][2] == '0') or \
                (self.p[0][0] == '0' and
                 self.p[1][1] == '0' and
                 self.p[2][2] == '0') or \
                (self.p[0][2] == '0' and
                 self.p[1][1] == '0' and
                 self.p[2][0] == '0') or \
                (self.p[0][0] == '0' and
                 self.p[1][0] == '0' and
                 self.p[2][0] == '0') or \
                (self.p[0][1] == '0' and
                 self.p[1][1] == '0' and
                 self.p[2][1] == '0') or \
                (self.p[0][2] == '0' and
                 self.p[1][2] == '0' and
                 self.p[2][2] == '0'):
            return '0'
        elif '-' not in self.p[0] and \
                '-' not in self.p[1] and \
                '-' not in self.p[2]:
            return 'D'
        else:
            return 'None'

    def make_move(self, row, col):
        if self.p[row - 1][col - 1] == '-':
            self.n += 1
            self.p[row - 1][col - 1] = self.list[self.n % 2]
            if (self.p[0][0] == 'X' and
                self.p[0][1] == 'X' and
                self.p[0][2] == 'X') or \
                    (self.p[1][0] == 'X' and
                     self.p[1][1] == 'X' and
                     self.p[1][2] == 'X') or \
                    (self.p[2][0] == 'X' and
                     self.p[2][1] == 'X' and
                     self.p[2][2] == 'X') or \
                    (self.p[0][0] == 'X' and
                     self.p[1][1] == 'X' and
                     self.p[2][2] == 'X') or \
                    (self.p[0][2] == 'X' and
                     self.p[1][1] == 'X' and
                     self.p[2][0] == 'X') or \
                    (self.p[0][0] == 'X' and
                     self.p[1][0] == 'X' and
                     self.p[2][0] == 'X') or \
                    (self.p[0][1] == 'X' and
                     self.p[1][1] == 'X' and
                     self.p[2][1] == 'X') or \
                    (self.p[0][2] == 'X' and
                     self.p[1][2] == 'X' and
                     self.p[2][2] == 'X'):
                self.end_info = 'Игра уже завершена'
                return 'Победил игрок X'
            elif (self.p[0][0] == '0' and
                  self.p[0][1] == '0' and
                  self.p[0][2] == '0') or \
                    (self.p[1][0] == '0' and
                     self.p[1][1] == '0' and
                     self.p[1][2] == '0') or \
                    (self.p[2][0] == '0' and
                     self.p[2][1] == '0' and
                     self.p[2][2] == '0') or \
                    (self.p[0][0] == '0' and
                     self.p[1][1] == '0' and
                     self.p[2][2] == '0') or \
                    (self.p[0][2] == '0' and
                     self.p[1][1] == '0' and
                     self.p[2][0] == '0') or \
                    (self.p[0][0] == '0' and
                     self.p[1][0] == '0' and
                     self.p[2][0] == '0') or \
                    (self.p[0][1] == '0' and
                     self.p[1][1] == '0' and
                     self.p[2][1] == '0') or \
                    (self.p[0][2] == '0' and
                     self.p[1][2] == '0' and
                     self.p[2][2] == '0'):
                self.end_info = 'Игра уже завершена'
                return 'Победил игрок 0'
            elif '-' not in self.p[0] and \
                    '-' not in self.p[1] and \
                    '-' not in self.p[2]:
                self.end_info = 'Игра уже завершена'
                return 'Ничья'
            else:
                return 'Продолжаем играть'
        elif self.end_info != 0:
            return self.end_info
        else:
            return 'Клетка ' + str(row) + ', ' + str(col) + ' уже занята'
```

---

Помогите пожалуйста дописать код чтобы игра запускалась и корректно работала

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Этот код не похож на нормальный код игры "крестики нолики", вам для начала необходимо пройти уроки по циклам и потом приступать к реализации этой игры.

Comment: Но этот код ведь можно запустить?

Comment: Нужно запустить конкретно этот код, если есть возможность, помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и было сказано для начала вам стоило бы пройти уроки по циклам и потом приступать к реализации этой игры. Если нужно запустить именно этот код, то добавьте в конце следущие строки кода:

```
t = TicTacToeBoard()
t.new_game()

while (t.end_info == 0):
  row, col = [int(x) for x in input("Введите строку и столбец: ").split()]
  print(t.make_move(row, col))

  for i in t.p:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!